# Passar valor de uma view para modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Iniciando meus estudos em MVC estou fazendo um cadastro de CDs.
Acontece que eu tenho uma view com detalhes do artista (Artistas/Details/1).
Nesta View, tenho um botão "Novo" para digitar um novo CD do artista e que abre uma janela modal para isso (Trabalhos/Create).
Precisaria "passar" para essa modal o **nome** do artista que está no Artistas/Details/**1**.
Como isso é possível?
O código do button está assim:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btnCreate" style="width: 220px; background-color:darkseagreen">Novo</a>
```

para abrir o modal está assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(".btnCreate").click(function () {
        $("#modal").load("/Trabalhos/Create/", function () {
            $('#myModal').modal("show");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código html do modal.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, a modal irá abrir a view Create:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table style="margin:auto">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = true } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="margin:auto">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ano, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ano, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ano, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="margin:auto">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Artista, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </td>
            <td>
                **AQUI É QUE MOSTRARIA O NOME DO ARTISTA**
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <hr />

    <table style="margin:auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Confirma inclusão" class="btn btn-success" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btnBack">Cancela</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```